# SharePoint 2013 Populate list from external RSS

Tags: rss, sharepoint-2013

I'm new to Sharepoint development, I've been googling for a long time but so far I couldn't find an answer, maybe some of you can point me in the right direction. Is there any way to populate a list whit RSS feeds that comes from an external website? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you want populate a list with a RSS ? Anyway you can write some javascript for read RSS and insert into list with REST api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will help you

http://sharepoint-videos.com/module-1/pull-info-from-a-blogs-rss-feed-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/